# GoogleTest test error print of enum class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, enums, googletest

I'm using GoogleTest version 1.7.0 to test my C++ application. I have an enum defined as following

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    enum class MyEnum {
        MyEnumValue,
        MyEnumValue2
    }
}
```

GoogleTest incorrectly prints it's value, resulting in this error message when the test fails:

> Value of: MyClass.MyMethodThatReturnsEnum()
>
> Actual: 4-byte object
>
> Expected: MyEnum::MyEnumValue
>
> Which is: 4-byte object <02-00 00-00>

Removing the `class` keyword produces the correct error message with the real value of the enum. Is this a known behaviour/bug of GoogleTest? Is there a way to fix the problem?

```
MyClass my_class;

EXPECT_EQ(MyEnum::MyEnumValue, my_class.MyMethodThatReturnsEnum());
```

Answer (score 4):

When you define constants in `enum class MyEnum` you define them as objects
*of user-defined type* `MyEnum` from which there is no implicit conversion
to any integral type. That is the *goal* of `enum class` and it's not
for Googletest to assume you want objects of type `MyEnum` automatically
converted to an integral type for the purpose of inserting to an output
stream, if you have chosen to make that type an `enum class` and not just
an `enum`.

So what you observe isn't a Googletest error. It's just Googletest using its
fallback representation of a user-defined object of some type `T` for which

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, T const &);
```

is undefined.

If you want to see the integral values of objects of type `enum class MyEnum`
appear in Googletest's diagnostics for a test, you have at least two ways.

One way is to simply apply the test to *the underlying integral values* of the objects,
as in:

**main.cpp (1)**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <type_traits>

enum class MyEnum {
    Value,
    Value2
};

auto as_integral(MyEnum me)
-> std::underlying_type<MyEnum>::type
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type<MyEnum>::type>(me);
}

TEST(foo,bar)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(as_integral(MyEnum::Value),as_integral(MyEnum::Value2));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -o gtester main.cpp -lgtest  -lpthread
$ ./gtester
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from foo
[ RUN      ] foo.bar
main.cpp:17: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  as_integral(MyEnum::Value)
    Which is: 0
  as_integral(MyEnum::Value2)
    Which is: 1
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from foo (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Another - better - way is to provide Googletest with a definition of:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, MyEnum const &);
```

that suits you. Then Googletest will use it in its diagnostics, as in:

**main.cpp (2)**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ostream>

enum class MyEnum {
    Value,
    Value2
};

auto as_integral(MyEnum me)
-> std::underlying_type<MyEnum>::type
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type<MyEnum>::type>(me);
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, MyEnum me)
{
    return out << as_integral(me);
}

TEST(foo,bar)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(MyEnum::Value,MyEnum::Value2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -o gtester main.cpp -lgtest  -lpthread
$ ./gtester
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from foo
[ RUN      ] foo.bar
main.cpp:23: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  MyEnum::Value
    Which is: 0
  MyEnum::Value2
    Which is: 1
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from foo (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that `enum classes`(officially named scoped enums) do not necessarily have the same size as `enums`(officially named unscoped enums).

The compiler decides which size is appropriate for your enum . `Enum classes` have a default size. This is why `enum classes` are easy to forward declare.

It looks like the test framework does not distinguish between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. However, I still don't understand why GoogleTest prints the enum value as bytes. Shouldn't it be just a comparison? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework but I would guess that it prints all objects this way. A 64 bit object would be printed as 8 bytes for example. You can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Furthermore the way it prints the message should have no bearing on the EXPECT_EQ() function.

Comment: GoogleTest is able to print different C++ types, like std::string or std::vector objects with their real value using the PrintTo function. It seems to me that it's not able to understand the difference between scoped and normal enums, but I don't see the correlation between the binary size and this problem

Comment: The problem could arise if the comparison of values inside of EXPECT_EQU() detects and forbids downconversions so that it does not consider a char of value 8 equal to a long of value 8 for example.

Comment: After some debugging into GoogleTest source code I found that it prints byte data because testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const MyEnum&, testing::internal::BiggestInt>::value returns false, but I have no knowledge to understand deeper the reason of this

Comment: After extended research, I found that scoped enums can't be implicit casted to int, so this seems to be the reason that causes that like to returns false.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom printing: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values

I offer these in the mock implementations of the interfaces.