# How to implement a custom value printer for googletest for std enums

Tags: c++, std, googletest

I want to have a value printer for the `std::future_status` enum.
Basically a better error message for than this:

```
[ RUN      ] BasicTest.AssertNotEqualFutureStatus
Expected equality of these values:
  a
    Which is: 4-byte object <00-00 00-00>
  b
    Which is: 4-byte object <01-00 00-00>
```

Normally one would just implement `PrintTo` or `<<` to do that.
Ref: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values and [GoogleTest test error print of enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346182/googletest-test-error-print-of-enum-class)

Problem is extending the `std` namespace is undefined behaviour.
And i don't want to just print it after this output which can be done with `<<` or `SCOPED_TRACE`.

Code

```
TEST(setup_test_case, testWillPass)
{
  auto a = std::future_status::ready;
  auto b = std::future_status::timeout;
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fqPnnh9x1

Is there a way to extend the value printer from googletest without UB?

Answer (score 2):

Overloading `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T&)` is a normal practice, it does not extend the `std` namespace. Moreover, `4-byte object <00-00 00-00>` could be the output of googletest overloaded operator (actually it is a bit complicated, done with using `UniversalTersePrinter<T>::Print()`)

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T&);
```

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <future>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::future_status& status) {
  os << static_cast<int>(status);  // whatever needed to print status to os
  return os;
}

TEST(setup_test_case, testWillPass)
{
  auto a = std::future_status::ready;
  auto b = std::future_status::timeout;
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
}
```

```
[ RUN      ] setup_test_case.testWillPass
example.cpp:13: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  a
    Which is: 0
  b
    Which is: 1
[  FAILED  ] setup_test_case.testWillPass (0 ms)
```

Comment: However, FWIW, this would break if some future C++ standard version adds its own `operator<<()` overload for `std::future_status` to the std namespace.

Comment: It will break, i.e. it will yield something like: `/usr/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:287:7: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const std::future_status’)`

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior to add overloads to `std` that do not depend on a user defined type (as in this case)? I think there is no standard abiding way to do what the OP wants.

Comment: Extending the std namespace as 273K here shows works but i am pretty sure according to the standard this is considered an illegal extension to the std namespace which can lead to UB

Comment: @Sedenion 273K's answer does **NOT** add an overload to the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Sirl33tname This answer does **NOT** extend the std namespace. Hence, it doesn't introduce UB. It 'just' introduces the possibility of compile-breaking ambiguity, if the standard adds `operator<<()` for that enum.